# Installing Gentoo packages as an ordinary user (non-root)

Tags: software-installation, gentoo, non-root-user

Is it possible to install Gentoo packages (ebuild-enabled programs, programs with support for portage) as an ordinary user (non-root) to one's own home directory (`--prefix=$HOME` or something like that)?

Comment: portage is very flexible, and I'd hazard a guess that with the right environment variable settings it could be done. But I'm not exactly sure what they would be right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this should be doable using [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/).

> Usually, Gentoo's Portage installs in
>   the root of the filesystem hierarchy,
>   '/'. On systems other than Gentoo
>   Linux, this usually results in
>   problems, due to conflicts of software
>   packages, unless the OS is adapted
>   like Gentoo/FreeBSD. Instead, Gentoo
>   Prefix installs with an offset,
>   allowing to install in another
>   location in the filesystem hierarchy,
>   hence avoiding conflicts. Next to this
>   offset, Gentoo Prefix runs
>   unprivileged, meaning no root user or
>   rights are required to use it.

Comment: Could you give me *step by step* instruction how to install given package locally?

Comment: I think you'll be better off reading the docs, they're more accurate than anything I could reproduce here.

Comment: Unfortunately from first browsing they do require good konwledge of Gentoo... and I am just beginning to use computer with Gentoo installed.  As far as I have checked they lack step by step instruction.  Still, I'll be trying.

Comment: follow the solaris guide like they suggest: http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/bootstrap-solaris.xml