# Installing Chrome on 64bit Gentoo without Superuser Access

Tags: gentoo, non-root-user, chrome

For a bit of background, I am trying to install Chrome (or Chromium) on to a gentoo user account at my university. We are allowed to install software as we like, however we lack superuser access meaning I cannot just run `emerge google-chrome`.

Attempting to unpack the 64-bit .rpm provided by google and run it out of my user directory provided me with this:

```
$ ./chrome/google/chrome/google-chrome
./chrome/google/chrome/google-chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libcups.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't have access to `rpm2cpio` (rendering the only other answer I could find less than helpful) but I do have access to `rpmunpack` and a whole host of `rpm2[insert archive type here]` commands.

Comment: If you can live with chromium (open source variant of google-chrome) you can build it yourself.

Comment: According to the Linux Build Instructions page, a full build requires 10GB of space. Sadly, this is too much space.

Comment: Needs a ton of swap space too, if you have less then 4GB of system memory available during compile.

Comment: Chrome dpeends on a lot of libraries (such as `libcups`), you'll have to install them. They should all be in Gentoo, and they're useful for more than Chrome. If you can, convince your system administrator to install them.

Comment: Does this help? [Installing Gentoo packages as an ordinary user (non-root)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13937) Install the libraries first, then Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Setup basic Gentoo VM, mark files, install Chrome (normal tools) and copy files installed after basic setup (including additional libraries).